# How to find point by input search in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I'm going to create 3D Earth with search input. Could someone guide how to write code that finds point (exact place point) by input search, using WebGL?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is really vague but I can imagine that what you want to do is to rotate your 3D Earth so the point you queried for appears in the center of the view (or what it is the same, on the view axis of the camera).

To do it you need to:

1. assign every landmark a set of
   [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates)
2. given that you are locating
   points on the surface of the sphere
   you can forget about the radius and
   only assign **elevation** and
   **azimuth** to each point.
3. then you write the code for the
   user to input the point of interest.
   Say "Rome".
4. you look for this point in a
       javascript array and recover the
       **elevation** and the **azimuth** values
5. you apply the correspondent
   rotations to your Model-View Matrix. Assuming you are using [glMatrix](http://code.google.com/p/glmatrix/source/browse/glMatrix.js) you
   should have something like this:

   ```
   var M = mat4.create();
   var Y_axis = [0,1,0];
   var X_axis = [1,0,0];
   mat4.rotate(M,azimuth,Y_axis);
   mat4.rotate(M,elevation,X_axis);
   ```
6. the point of interest should be
   displayed now